# Adding XML to asdoc function comments in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, asdoc

How do you add sample xml to asdoc function/class comments in Flex? They can obviously be added, but they wont show in the hover asdoc comments in Flash Builder 4.

```
/**
* Generates a ChangeAccount in xml format when they are being saved 
* 
* <p>Will be in the following form  
*  Use http://xmlindent.com/ to view pretty xml format)
*  
*  <ChangeAccount History="w" Alias="transaction".............
* </p>
*
* @return XML
*/
public function get xml():XML
{           
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape the '<' and '>' with & lt; and & gt;  ( Note: remove the spaces )

> & lt;ChangeAccount History="w"
>   Alias="transaction"............. /& gt;

Comment: Ah yeah, didnt consider that. www.xmlindent.com will show it in pretty xml format even with the &lt &gt, so this will work, thnks